# start indexing in elasticsearch with cakephp2.6

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, cakephp-2.6

when i run     `cake Elastic.elastic index Contact`

not working i have this message error

```
D:\wamp\www\elasticsh\app>cake Elastic.elastic index Contact

Notice Error: Array to string conversion in [D:\wamp\www\elasticsh\app\Plugin\El
astic\Console\Command\ElasticShell.php, line 263]

Retrieving data from mysql starting on Array
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server vers
ion for the right syntax to use near '= ('2012-07-19 20:31:29')   ORDER BY `Cont
act`.`modified` ASC  LIMIT 100' at line 1
#0 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource
\DboSource.php(458): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource
\DboSource.php(424): DboSource->_execute('SELECT `Contact...', Array)
#2 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource
\DboSource.php(666): DboSource->execute('SELECT `Contact...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource
\DboSource.php(1104): DboSource->fetchAll('SELECT `Contact...', false)
#4 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(
3018): DboSource->read(Object(Contact), Array)
#5 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(
2990): Model->_readDataSource('all', Array)
#6 D:\wamp\www\elasticsh\app\Plugin\Elastic\Console\Command\ElasticShell.php(296
): Model->find('all', Array)
#7 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.ph
p(445): ElasticShell->index()
#8 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDis
patcher.php(209): Shell->runCommand('index', Array)
#9 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDis
patcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\cakephp-2.6.0\cakephp-2.6.0\lib\Cake\Console\cake.ph
p(54): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#11 {main}
```